# What does this mean? Variable declared followed by a block without assignment

Tags: swift

Noob Swift question--I can't figure out what this means in Swift:

```
public var currentTime: NSTimeInterval? {
    return self.audioPlayer?.currentTime
}
```

`currentTime` isn't being assigned to the block of code after `NSTimeInterval?`so what does this mean? I can't an example like this in my reference books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same as:

```
public var currentTime: NSTimeInterval? {
    get { return self.audioPlayer?.currentTime }
}
```

When your computed property only has a `get`, you can omit the word `get` and the curly brackets.

From the [swift guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html):

> You can simplify the declaration of a read-only computed property by removing the get keyword and its braces:

Answer (score 1):

This is called `Read-Only Computed Properties`

According to Apple Docs

> A computed property with a getter but no setter is known as a read-only computed property. A read-only computed property always returns a value, and can be accessed through dot syntax, but cannot be set to a different value.

For more info [Computed Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little playground for clarification:

```
//: Computed properties

import UIKit

var variable_int = 1

var computed_int: Int {
get { return 1 }
set { newValue }
}

var get_only_int: Int {
  return 1
}

var get_only_int_2: Int {
get { return 1 }
}

variable_int = 2 // legal
computed_int = 2 // legal

// computed_read_only_int = 2   // 'computed_read_only_int' is a get-only property
// computed_read_only_int_2 = 2 // 'computed_read_only_int_2' is a get-only property


// This is another way to specify a variable you could find useful, I found it somewhere on natashatherobot.com
var variable_int_2: Int = {
  return 1
}()

variable_int_2 = 2 // legal
```

works in Xcode 8.1